# How can I create coordinates that almost border my GameScene?

Tags: ios, swift, random, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to generate circles that nearly border the edge of the screen. I tried creating my own coordinate generator, my issue is that the circles that I am randomly generating are only appearing at the top and bottom of the screen. Here is a screenshot of what it is doing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBUSP.jpg

I have no idea why this is happening because when I print the x and y coordinate of the circle's position, it says that both points are less than the frame's width and height. In my `GameScene.swift` I call this function.

```
    private func generateRandomCoorindates() -> CGPoint {

    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2)
    var xCoordinate: Double
    var yCoordinate: Double
    if randomNumber == 0 {
        var _xCoordinate: Double {
           let _randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2)
            //x-corrdinate either 50 or width-50
            if _randomNumber == 0 {
                return 50
            } else {
                return Double(self.frame.width - 50)
            }
        }
        xCoordinate = _xCoordinate
        //random y-coordinate from 50 to height-50
        yCoordinate = Double.random(lower: 50, upper: Double(self.frame.height) - 50)
    }
    else {
        //random x-coordinate from 50 to width-50
        xCoordinate = Double.random(lower: 50, upper: Double(self.frame.width) - 50)
        var _yCoordinate: Double {
            //y-coordinate either 50 or height - 50
            let _randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2)
            if _randomNumber == 0 {
                return 50
            } else {
                return Double(self.frame.height - 50)
            }
        }
        yCoordinate = _yCoordinate
        }
    return CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xCoordinate), y: CGFloat(yCoordinate))
    }
```

My extensions are:

```
public func arc4random <T: IntegerLiteralConvertible> (type: T.Type) -> T {
var r: T = 0
arc4random_buf(&r, Int(sizeof(T)))
return r
}

public extension Double {
    public static func random(lower lower: Double, upper: Double) -> Double {
        let r = Double(arc4random(UInt64)) / Double(UInt64.max)
        return (r * (upper - lower)) + lower
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain why you've chosen to extend `Double` when you only need one computed property - it seems to be overcomplicating things. Here's a function that will return a random point somewhere along the edge of the screen, and requires a lot less code.

```
let screenwidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let screenheight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

func randomCoordinates -> CGPoint {
    var coordinates = CGPoint()

    let randomX = arc4random(screenwidth) - screenwidth/2  // subtracting half of the screen to center it
    let randomY = arc4random(screenheight) - screenheight/2

    let randomDirection = arc4random_uniform(4)
    switch randomDirection {
    case 0: returnCoordinates = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: screenheight/2)  // north edge
    case 1: returnCoordinates = CGPoint(x: screenwidth/2, y: randomY)  // east edge
    case 2: returnCoordinates = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: -screenheight/2)  // south edge
    case 3: returnCoordinates = CGPoint(x: -screenwidth/2, y: randomY)  // west edge
    }

    return coordinates
}
```

Comment: Yep this is a much cleaner way of doing it, thank you. P.S. one of the weird issues I was having was I didn't set this `self.size = view.bounds.size` in `didMoveToView`. Just in case anyone comes across this issue